# How can I retain desired order in R Plotly bar chart with color variable

Tags: r, plotly

Pretty self-evident. Values on x-axis are not ordered correctly if color parameter is invoked

```
df <- structure(list(count = c(8, 3, 5, 9), names = c("I", "want", 
"this", "order"), type = c("H", "A", "H", "A")), .Names = c("count", 
"names", "type"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")

plot_ly(data=df,x=names,y=count,type="bar",
   color = type)
```

[image] 
This is somewhat similar to [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34643272/color-in-plotly-bar-chart) but that seemed a bit of a hack that may be difficult to apply here anyways

TIA

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Update: plotly_4.5.6 included some changes (original answer below the horizontal rule)

My original answer could be modified to:

```
p <- plot_ly(data = df, x = ~names, y = ~count, type = "bar", color = ~type)
p <- layout(p, xaxis = list(categoryarray = ~names, categoryorder = "array"))
p
```

Or

You can take advantage of changes made to plotly (read more [here](http://moderndata.plot.ly/upgrading-to-plotly-4-0-and-above/)):

> Also, the order of categories on a discrete axis, by default, is now
>   either alphabetical (for character strings) or matches the ordering of
>   factor levels.

```
# set the factor order however you want
df$names <- factor(df$names,
                   levels = c("I", "want", "this", "order"))
# plot it (note, plotly can now infer the trace, but I specified as "bar" anyway
plot_ly(data = df, x = ~names, y = ~count, color = ~type, type = "bar")
```

---

#### Original Answer

Use `layout` and the arguments you can feed to `xaxis`.  Specifically, you want to set `categoryarray = name` and `categoryorder = "array"`.  From the layout section of https://plot.ly/r/reference/:

> Set `categoryorder` to "array" to derive the ordering from the
>   attribute `categoryarray`.

```
p <- plot_ly(data=df, x=names, y=count, type="bar", color = type)
p <- layout(p, xaxis = list(categoryarray = names, categoryorder = "array"))
p
```

Comment: #Jota. Thanks for answer(which works) and reference link. Looking at the reference , I'm still not sure why it needs this layout line at all as "By default, plotly uses "trace", which specifies the order that is present in the data supplied" and the dataframe names order is "I","want","this","order"??

Comment: @pssguy I agree with you that it is confusing.  Not sure, but I am guessing that if it's not a bug, "the data supplied" could mean the data as supplied in the html file: `"data":[{"type":"bar","inherit":false,"x":["I","this"],"y":[8,5],"name":"H","marker":{"color":"#66C2A5"}},{"type":"bar","inherit":false,"x":["want","order"],"y":[3,9],"name":"A","marker":{"color":"#8DA0CB"}}]` and not the data supplied as input.

Comment: @jota I think it's worth mentioning that there is a breaking change in plotly 4.0 as described here http://moderndata.plot.ly/upgrading-to-plotly-4-0-and-above/