# How do I make error bars match data in R Plotly

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, r-plotly

I'm trying to display a bar chart with error bars.  When I add a color variable, the error bars are displayed on the wrong bars.

```
df <- data_frame(label = c("Step 1", "Step 2", "Step 3", "Step 4"), 
             Action = c("DISPENSE", "WAIT", "DISPENSE", "WAIT" ), 
             Avg = c(1.65, 3.88, 1.19, 23.09),
             StdDev = c(0.80, 7.54, 0.11, 14.63)) 

p1 <- plot_ly(df, type = "bar", orientation = 'h', 
    y = ~label, x = ~Avg, color = ~Action,
    error_x = list(type = "data", array = ~StdDev, color = "#000000"),
    text = ~paste0(Avg," (+/- ",StdDev,")"), hoverinfo = "text")

p2 <- plot_ly(df, type = "bar", orientation = 'h', 
    y = ~label, x = ~Avg,
    error_x = list(type = "data", array = ~StdDev, color = "#000000"),
    text = ~paste0(Avg," (+/- ",StdDev,")"), hoverinfo = "text")

subplot(p1, p2, nrows=2)
```

this is the output of the plot:

[image: Plot output image]

I want the chart to be colored by Action, like in `p1`, but with the error bars correctly assigned for each row, like in `p2`.

I've tried various forms for the `error_x` parameters, without success:

```
error_x = ~list(type = "data", array = StdDev, color = "#000000")
error_x = ~list(type = "array", array = StdDev, color = "#000000")
error_x = list(type = "array", array = ~StdDev, color = "#000000")
```

I suspect it's similar to [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38839657/), or they're both caused by the same bug.  I wasn't able to implement their solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Passing an array to `color` causes more changes than just having colored bars, it also splits the data in multiple traces.

If you want both, different colors and different traces, I don't see any other solution except for creating the traces manually.

In the first graph the colors are assigned manually, in the 2nd graph for each unique `Action` value a new trace is created.

```
library(tibble)
library(plyr)
library(plotly)

df <- data_frame(label = c("Step 1", "Step 2", "Step 3", "Step 4"), 
                 Action = c("DISPENSE", "WAIT", "DISPENSE", "WAIT" ), 
                 Avg = c(1.65, 3.88, 1.19, 23.09),
                 StdDev = c(0.80, 7.54, 0.11, 14.63)) 

color_choices <- list("#8DA0CB", "#59C5A3")
colors <- mapvalues(df$Action, unique(df$Action), color_choices)
p1 <- plot_ly(df, type = "bar", orientation = 'h', 
              y = ~label, x = ~Avg,
              error_x = list(type = "data", array = ~StdDev),
              text = ~paste0(Avg," (+/- ",StdDev,")"), hoverinfo = "text",
              marker = list(color = colors))

p2 <- plot_ly()
names(color_choices) <- unique(df$Action)

for (action in unique(df$Action))
{
  df_filtered <- filter(df, Action == action)
  p2 <- plotly::add_bars(p2, orientation = 'h',
                         y = df_filtered$label, x = df_filtered$Avg,
                         error_x = list(type = "data", array = df_filtered$StdDev), 
                         text = ~paste0(df_filtered$Avg," (+/- ", df_filtered$StdDev, ")"),
                         color = color_choices[action][[1]],
                         hoverinfo = "text",
                         name = action)

}
subplot(p1, p2, nrows=2)
```

[image]