# Retain original bar order in Plotly Python when also passing color

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, plotly-python

Using Plotly for a bar plot preserves the dataset's order when not using `color`:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame({'val': [1, 2, 3],
                   'type': ['b', 'a', 'b']},
                  index=['obs1', 'obs2', 'obs3'])
px.bar(df, 'val')
```

[image]
But `color` reorders the data:

```
px.bar(df, 'val', color='type')
```

[image]

How can I preserve the original ordering while using the `color` arg?

This is similar to [How can I retain desired order in R Plotly bar chart with color variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38839657/how-can-i-retain-desired-order-in-r-plotly-bar-chart-with-color-variable), but I'm using Python rather than R.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use the `category_orders` parameter:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame({'val': [1, 2, 3],
                   'type': ['b', 'a', 'b']},
                  index=['obs1', 'obs2', 'obs3'])
fig = px.bar(df, 'val', color='type', category_orders={'index': df.index[::-1]})
fig.show()
```

**Output**

[image]

From the [documentation](https://plotly.github.io/plotly.py-docs/generated/plotly.express.html):

> This parameter is used to force a specific ordering of values per
> column. The keys of this dict should correspond to column names, and
> the values should be lists of strings corresponding to the specific
> display order desired.

By looking at the [code](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/blob/master/packages/python/plotly/plotly/express/_core.py#L1636) it seems that `color` is being used as a grouping attribute, so that's probably why the reordering is happening.

Answer (score 5):

I don't really know why plotly express do it, but you can use a workaround as using an array to reorder the yaxis `fig.update_layout( yaxis={'categoryorder':'array', 'categoryarray':df.index})`:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame({'val': [1, 2, 3],
                   'type': ['b', 'a', 'b']},
                  index=['obs1', 'obs2', 'obs3'])
fig=px.bar(df, x='val',y=df.index, orientation='h')


fig=px.bar(df, x='val',y=df.index, color='type', orientation='h')
fig.update_layout( yaxis={'categoryorder':'array', 'categoryarray':df.index})
```

result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Plotly express seems to group the data according to color when color='type' is used. The following worked for me and kept bars' order:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame({'val': [1, 2, 3],
               'type': ['b', 'a', 'b']},
              index=['obs1', 'obs2', 'obs3'])

fig=px.bar(df, x='val',y=df.index)
fig.update_traces(marker_color=['#ebb36a' if i=='a' else '#6dbf9c' for i in df.type]
, showlegend=False)
```